# Access token could not be verified - drupal simple ouath

Tags: oauth-2.0, drupal

i'm trying to generate new access token using Simple oauth (v 5.2.3) module in drupal 9 ,
when I generate private and public keys from module settings , the private and public key files created but the are empty .
and when I generate them by another way , this error shows
[image]

and Drupal Log shows this error message :

> League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException: The resource owner or authorization server denied the request. in League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::accessDenied()

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Try to add your client's secret again into the OAuth Clients on the following path: `/admin/config/services/consumer`
- Clear the Drupal cache
- Get your new access token using your credentials
  [image: Access Token]
- Get your data using the new access token
  [image: Get the data]